# How to create alias for targets using CMake?

Tags: makefile, cmake, alias

Suppose that I've got the following library:

```
add_library(myLib STATIC ${SRC_FILES})
```

In order to make this lib, I have to execute the following command:

```
make myLib
```

How can I create an alias for `myLib`, like `lib`, so that executing the following line makes the same target?

```
make lib
```

Comment: This command `add_library(<name> ALIAS <target>)` might do what you need.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
add_library(foo foo.cpp )
add_custom_target(bar DEPENDS foo)
```

Comment: Thank you. Could you please answer this question too? http://stackoverflow.com/q/21852817/69537